# Android Studio Corrupts Base64 String When Trying To Upload

Tags: php, android, base64

So I am testing methods to upload an image to a php server. One of the methods was to convert the image to a `Base64` String and upload it and then decode it when needed.

When I uploaded a picture I noticed that there was a difference in the Strings. **Some spaces were missing and some next lines were misplaced**.

Before I sent the string to the server the string is okay and then it goes through a `_POST` command in the php file and then it is inserted into the database using `INSERT INTO`.

I suspect that the header that I use changes the string when I try to upload it. the header is `/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I tried using `/json` but if the json object is converted to string it changes the original string. So what header do I need to use so the string won't change? Or **is there another method to upload a picture to a `MySQL` database?**

This is the method I use to upload the string to the server:

```
ImageString = getStringImage(bitmap); 
String ImageUploadString="image="+ImageString; 
final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient(); 
MediaType contentType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"); 

RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(contentType, imageUploadString)); 
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(uploadURL).post(body).build(); 
Response response = null; 
try { 
    response = client.newCall(request).execute(); 
} catch (IOException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
} 
try { 
    String json = response.body().string(); 
} catch (IOException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Edit: this is the php file that I use to insert the picture:

```
<?php
$response = array();
if (isset($_POST['image']))
{
$image = $_POST['image'];
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO images(image) VALUES('$image')");
if ($result) {
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "missing fields";
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: check this [link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server-using-php-mysql/) It's exactly what u want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For image uploads you can always go for multipart part upload rather than converting it into base64. If you are using retrofit, the implementation will be easier.

I am adding the php and the android code to do it. I assume you are using httpurlconnection and not retrofit.

**PHP**

```
  <?php
            $target_dir = "uploads/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
            $uploadOk = 1;
            $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
            if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
                if($check !== false) {
                    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                    $uploadOk = 1;
                } else {
                    echo "File is not an image.";
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }
            }
            // Check if file already exists
            if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            // Check file size
            if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
                echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            // Allow certain file formats
            if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
            && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
                echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
            if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
            // if everything is ok, try to upload file
            } else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
                } else {
                    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                }
            }
            ?>
```

**Android**

```
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(_filePath));

        URL url = new URL(urlServer);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs & Outputs
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        // Enable POST method
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                connection.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream
                .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileToUpload\";filename=\""
                        + _filePath + "\"" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        // int contentLength = bytesAvailable+
        // header.getBytes().length+footer.getBytes().length;

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                + lineEnd);
```

I also suggest you to use retrofit as a lot of network handling are done by the library itself.

Comment: Can you please add to your answer how to do it? I will add to the question the php file that I use to upload, I am new to php.

Comment: Also I am getting a lot of errors. Most of the variables here are not defined and I do not know their type or what they contain. And I added the dependency to the gradle file but I do not know how to use retrofit.

Comment: From the above code you will get a basic idea. Please follow this tutorial https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client for retrofit.

Comment: Any chance for a ready project that works?
I have searched and tried methods, but I am having trouble understanding how to use retrofit

Comment: Where you able to do it with httpurlconnection?

Comment: It didn't work, the guides had many custom add-ons that weren't covered in the guide or they didn't work for me. Isn't there a simple way to upload a picture to a cloud or a simple way to upload to a php server?

Comment: I tried using retrofit, this guide seems like the most promising but the app shuts down when I press the upload FAB. http://www.pratikbutani.com/2016/06/android-upload-image-file-using-retrofit-2-0/

Comment: Please post the crash log.

Comment: The LogCat doesn't show any errors, it just shuts down without errors.
I am clueless of how to upload the picture at this moment and I do not have much time left to finish the program.

Comment: Tried to use the 000webhost with the tutorial that I posted in the comments and it worked, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, the data you are sending to the server is being encoded somehow by your `HttpClient`.

you just need to decode it in `php` code -

For an example,

Here I was sending device id to the server, *look how I did url decoding* -

```
if(isset($_POST['device_id']) && !empty($_POST['device_id']))
    $data->device_id = urldecode($_POST['device_id']);
```

Comment: So all I add to the file(I added the php file) is `urldecode()` to the string that I get? and how will it affect the string that the file is getting?

Comment: `Before I sent the string to the server the string is okay` - this statement explains that your http parameters are encoded by HttpClient that you're using (Okhttp). All you need to do is decode the string that you are getting for request. Try decoding and print the string, you'll get the result.

Comment: `$data->device_id` can you explain what this statement means so I can better understand how to use it

Comment: Its a `Yii` code. Keep it simple like `$device_id` that's all you need. Actually this is the way I used in my app. you can modify variable name and `POST` params

Comment: And I tried using `$image = urldecode($_POST['image']);` but still the spaces are missing.

Comment: Can you post your current result and expected result?

Comment: result: http://www.mediafire.com/file/dcqdze3w4k6eq28/result2.txt
expectation: http://www.mediafire.com/file/jltn679zl6c6cd6/expected.txt